# Track & Report Affiliate User Conversions which happen on a 3rd party site

Tags: php, wordpress, affiliate, affiliates

I want to track user visits & user conversions who come via my Affiliates, however a caveat is that my users will land, register and hence convert on a 3rd party site. I own a Wordpress website and my user registration page is hosted on a 3rd party. My Affiliates will send an email blast to their users with the email containing unique Affiliate link to register on that 3rd party. Successful registration page is also hosted on that 3rd party itself and hence my website never comes into picture during the entire process right from user landing to user conversion.

So essentially following are the basic features that I require:

- Ability to manage (create, edit, delete) Affiliates.
- Ability to generate required links, creatives and tracking pixels or any code which can help to track user visits and conversions.
- Ability to track the number of user impressions and user conversions per Affiliate including how many users from a particular Affiliate landed on the 3rd party registration page and which users (with basic details such as name, country etc.) actually got converted.
- Various reports mainly based on Date and Affiliates.

The 3rd part is ready to host some code (such as tracking pixel) from my side.

I have already tried using 'WP Affiliate Manager' plugin in Wordpress, however using its ‘Creatives’ and ‘Tracking Pixels’ can only report the impression/conversion, but not other user details such as Name, Country etc. which would be collected by the 3rd party on the registration page and hence my entire purpose is not fulfilled.

I need to get this done today. Please let me know what could be the quickest solution.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you are vCommission affiliate user then go through this link http://developers.hasoffers.com/#/affiliate/controller/Affiliate_AffiliateUser/method/findAll
You will got all user details after 14 days if he does shopping using your affiliate link.

Comment: essential part of the answer should be here